# why my text field show ??? in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

evrything is ok but my text is ???

```
       select sum(mande) jameMandeha,
   [عنوان]= 
  CASE 
       WHEN [ردیف] =1 THEN TRY_CAST(('سپرده های قرض الحسنه جاری - ریال') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
       WHEN [ردیف] =2 THEN  CAST(('سپرده های قرض الحسنه جاری - ارز') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
       WHEN [ردیف] =3 THEN  CAST(('انواع چک های فروخته شده') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))          
       WHEN [ردیف] =7 THEN  CAST(('وجوه اداره شده مصرف نشده - ریال') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))       
       WHEN [ردیف] =9 THEN  CAST(('بستانکاران موقت - ریال') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))        
       WHEN [ردیف] =10 THEN CAST(('بستانکاران موقت - ارز') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))        
       WHEN [ردیف] =11 THEN CAST(('[مانده مطالبه نشده - ریال]') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))       
  END,
  [ردیف],regdate from #tmp_res group by [ردیف],regdate order by [ردیف]
```

but have this result

```
3833456009228   ????? ??? ??? ?????? ???? - ????    1   1397/06/31
150763478110    ????? ??? ??? ?????? ???? - ???     2   1397/06/31
366674660068    ????? ?? ??? ?????? ???             3   1397/06/31
2103192861      ???? ????? ??? ???? ???? - ????     7   1397/06/31
2547718000      ?????????? ???? - ????              9   1397/11/29
1107433985359   ?????????? ???? - ????              9   1397/06/31
2979163         ?????????? ???? - ???               10  1397/06/31
12336285349     ????? ?????? ???? - ????            11  1397/06/31
```

thanks for read my problem,please help me

Comment: Preceed your literal string with an `N` (i.e. N'{Your Literal String'`). without the `N` you are saying your literal string is a `varchar`, not an `nvarchar`; which cannot hold unicode characters.

Comment: You also, therefore, don't need the `CAST`, `THEN N'Your unicode string'` will be fine.